# Getting error in firebase recyclerview in my released version of app

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm getting a "java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message" error in released version of app while displaying firebase recyclerview and app crashes. I'm not getting any kind of such error in the debug version of app and firebase recyclerview works normally.

I'm trying to display firebase recyclerview in release version as well.

```
Query query = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference()
            .child("userScore")
            .orderByChild("userScore")
            .limitToLast(100);

FirebaseRecyclerOptions<UserScoreModel> options =
            new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<UserScoreModel>()
                    .setQuery(query, UserScoreModel.class)
                    .build();

    adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserScoreModel, ScoreViewHolder>(options) {

        @Override
        public ScoreViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.item_score, viewGroup, false);

            return new ScoreViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public UserScoreModel getItem(int position){
            return  super.getItem(getItemCount()-position-1);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(ScoreViewHolder scoreViewHolder, int i, final UserScoreModel userScoreModel) {
            progDialog.dismiss();
            String userName = userScoreModel.getUserName();
            String score = String.valueOf(userScoreModel.getUserScore());
            userImage = storageRef.child("UserImage/" + userScoreModel.getUid() + userScoreModel.getProfileUrl() + ".jpeg");
            Log.w("username",userName);
            Log.w("score",score);

            if(i+1==1){
                name2.setText(userName);
                String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.Rs);
                String resultStr = mystring + " " +score;
                score2.setText(resultStr);
                GlideApp.with(getApplicationContext()).load(userImage).override(200, 200)
                        .circleCrop().placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boy1)).into(img2);

            }

            if(i+1==2){
                name1.setText(userName);
                String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.Rs);
                String resultStr = mystring + " " +score;
                score1.setText(resultStr);
                GlideApp.with(getApplicationContext()).load(userImage).override(200, 200)
                        .circleCrop().placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boy1)).into(img1);

            }

            if(i+1==3){
                name3.setText(userName);
                String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.Rs);
                String resultStr = mystring + " " +score;
                score3.setText(resultStr);
                GlideApp.with(getApplicationContext()).load(userImage).override(200, 200)
                        .circleCrop().placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boy1)).into(img3);

            }

            if (i+1<=3){
                scoreViewHolder.itemLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                scoreViewHolder.itemLinear.setLayoutParams(new RecyclerView.LayoutParams(0, 0));
            }

            if (i+1>3){
                String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.Rs);
                String resultStr = mystring + " " +score;
                scoreViewHolder.score.setText(resultStr);
                scoreViewHolder.nameOfPlayer.setText(userName);
                scoreViewHolder.rank.setText(String.valueOf(i+1));

                GlideApp.with(getApplicationContext()).load(userImage).override(200, 200)
                        .circleCrop().placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boy1)).into(scoreViewHolder.userImage);
            }



            userId = userScoreModel.getUid();

            if (userId.equals(uid)){
                String mystring = getResources().getString(R.string.Rs);
                String resultStr = mystring + " " +score;
                GlideApp.with(getApplicationContext()).load(userImage).override(200, 200)
                        .circleCrop().placeholder(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.boy1)).into(myImage);
                myRank.setText(String.valueOf(i+1));
                myName.setText(userName);
                myScore.setText(resultStr);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: It seems you are passing a null object to one of your `Log` call. You may try `Log.w("username", "" + userName);` to continue the execution and see what is going on.

Comment: you are right about that, it seems that was the error. But, it still does not display the recyclerview in release mode but it displays recyclerview in debug app. What is causing that to happen.

Comment: do you use flavors with your gradle ? to test release and debug versions?

Comment: No, i don't use flavors with my gradle.